# HTML/CSS Set a div into background

Tags: html, css, background

I want to set the `<div id="bar">...</div>` into the background.
First, here is my page: [tekkkz.com](http://tekkkz.com/posts/articles/arch_installation.html)

```
<div id="bar">
  <span id="views">50</span>
  <a class="icon-small" id="like"></a>
  <a class="icon-small" id="dislike"></a>
</div>
```

This block (on the top right with the like/dislike buttons) should be in the background, so that it wont take any width of my content box.

How to do this?

For better understanding: what i want to reach is similar to set a image anchor to page in libreoffice.

Comment: try to make its `position: absolute` this should take element from document elements flow and after this use `z-index` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `position: absolute` on your `<div id="bar">` and `position: relative` on it's parent. Then use `right: 0` if you want your element to be at the right corner of the content block.

```
#bar {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you. Also I added some code in my answer. Please mark it as the right answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

Since already in your stylesheet style.css

```
#bar{float:right;}
```

So you could just add in your pre block

```
<pre style="clear:both">
```

I tried it. It worked like charm.

Hope it help